# Handlebars precompiled template returning function text

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a precompiled template called "ReportOptions_Timeframe". When I call Handlebars.templates.ReportOptions_Timeframe(data) I do not get the rendered template html. Instead I get this for output:

> "function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
>   this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0']; helpers = this.merge(helpers,
>   Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};   var buffer = "", stack1,
>   helper, functionType="function",
>   escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression, self=this;
>
> function program1(depth0,data) {
>        var buffer = "";   buffer += "\r\n   "
>       + escapeExpression((typeof depth0 === functionType ? depth0.apply(depth0) : depth0))
>       + "\r\n  ";   return buffer;   }
>
> buffer += "Term:\r\n\r\n    ";   stack1 = helpers.each.call(depth0,
>   (depth0 && depth0.TermList),
>   {hash:{},inverse:self.noop,fn:self.program(1, program1,
>   data),data:data});   if(stack1 || stack1 === 0) { buffer += stack1; } 
>   buffer += "\r\n\r\n\r\n   \r\n\r\nDate range:\r\n\r\nto\r\n";   return buffer;   }"

What am I doing wrong?

Edited to add the precompiled template:

> (function() {   var template = Handlebars.template, templates =
>   Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
>   templates['ReportOptions_Timeframe'] = template(function
>   (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {   this.compilerInfo =
>   [4,'>= 1.0.0']; helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers);
>   data = data || {};
>
> return "function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {\n 
>   this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];\nhelpers = this.merge(helpers,
>   Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};\n  var buffer = \"\", stack1,
>   helper, functionType=\"function\",
>   escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression, self=this;\n\nfunction
>   program1(depth0,data) {\n  \n  var buffer = \"\";\n  buffer +=
>   \"\r\n  \"\n    + escapeExpression((typeof depth0 === functionType ? depth0.apply(depth0) : depth0))\n    + \"\r\n    \";\n  return
>   buffer;\n  }\n\n  buffer += \"Term:\r\n\r\n  \";\n  stack1 =
>   helpers.each.call(depth0, (depth0 && depth0.TermList),
>   {hash:{},inverse:self.noop,fn:self.program(1, program1,
>   data),data:data});\n  if(stack1 || stack1 === 0) { buffer += stack1;
>   }\n  buffer += \"\r\n\r\n\r\n   \r\n\r\nDate range:\r\n\r\nto\r\n\";\n  return buffer;\n  }";   }); })();

Comment: Please provide the code you are referring to. Do you have access to the template to show?

Comment: I have added the precompiled template as output by node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I was giving node the wrong input file. The input file I was using had been previously precompiled.